# How to convert date to type system.datetime in my PowerShells cript?

Tags: powershell, datetime, import-csv

I need to set `-accountexpiration` for multiple users in Active Directory using data from my CSV table with PowerShell. I have so far tried to do it with the command for a single user:

```
set-aduser -identity 'ABC' -accountexpirationdate 01/01/2020
```

which works fine, but when I import the csv and use the assigned variable with foreach, it says:

> Cannot convert value '01/01/2020' to type "system.datetime. Error: Sting was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Suppose my table is as follows:

samaccountname,edate
ABCD,01/01/2019
EFGH,02/02/2020

And I use the following script:

```
import-module activedirectory

$expirytable = import-csv 'c:\expire.csv'


foreach($user in $expirytable)

{

set-aduser -identity $expirytable.samaccountname -accountexpiration $expirytable.edate

}
```

I get:

> Cannot convert value "01/01/2020" to type "system.Datetime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I was missing I figured out please compare my codes to find mistake.

```
import-module activedirectory

$expirytable = import-csv 'c:\expire.csv'

foreach($user in $expirytable)

{

$username = $user.samaccountname
$edate = $user.edate

set-aduser -identity $username -accountexpiration $edate

}
```